# Auto rename extracting file with custom prefix during overwrite conflict using 7Zip

Tags: windows-7, 7-zip

I am trying to extract a .zip archive file which has files with same names, and later I want to manually check the conflicted files.

I have tried extracting it using 7Zip command line switch [`-aou`](https://sevenzip.osdn.jp/chm/cmdline/switches/overwrite.htm), which basically renames the extracting file in conflict by adding an underscore and a number ("name.txt will be renamed to name_1.txt").

```
7z x archive.zip -aou -ssc
```

This is what I get:
[extracted files screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xda5c.png)

There are already a few original files with "underscore and a number", which are not from the 'overwrite conflict' situation. I can't really know what were the conflicted files in the process.

So, I am thinking I could have figured it out if I can change the auto-rename feature of 7Zip, by adding a custom prefix.

Essentially, I want the extracted files to look like this:
[Desired filenames](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QF10A.png)

Is that possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For future reference, the way I solved it in five steps:

1. Using 7z commadn line, list all filenames to a txt file `7z l input.zip > filenames.txt`
2. From the `filenames.txt`, remove unique filnames, keeping duplicates. Use Excel or any other program. I used [TED Notepad](http://jsimlo.sk/notepad/).
3. Make a txt file with old filename on one line and the new filename (by adding prefix or whatever) on the next line. I call it `renames.txt`.
4. Use 7z command line to rename the files inside the archive. `7z rn input.zip -ssc @renames.txt`
5. Extract the archive with auto rename using 7z command line. `7z x input.zip -ssc -aou`